# Is it possible to use named ranges in Google spreadsheet queries so that the columns references are kept up to date?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-named-ranges

Using Google Spreadsheets, you can write [queries](http://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?answer=1388882). However, if you have column letters in quotes, then they aren't updated as column order changes.

Is there a way to write these queries so they don't need to be updated every time a column is added or removed?

Is it possible to use [named ranges](http://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?answer=63175) in queries to solve this problem?

Here's an example: If you add a column after 'F', then column 'G' gets pushed to 'H' and the meaning of the formula changes.

> =Query(B:J,"select avg(J) group by G")

**Related questions**

This question is not the same as [Using Query with column headers instead of column letters](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/87895/using-query-with-column-headers-instead-of-column-letters/) because this one is focused on the use of named ranges.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a kind of tricky, but it is possible with a helper Range and some concatenation.

What needs to be done:

1. Create a named range, COLS, to carry the column letters like this:

   ```
   A  
   B  
   C  
   D  
   E  
   ...
   ```

   Do it in a vertical way as shown.
2. Assemble the query string like this:

   ```
   =QUERY( B:J, "SELECT AVG(" & INDEX(**COLS**, COLUMN(J1)) & ") GROUP BY " & INDEX(**COLS**, COLUMN(G1)) )
   ```

Comment: The named range will work both in vertical or horizontal shape.

Comment: @Rubén is probably right.

Answer (score 5):

> Is there a way to write these queries so they don't need to be updated every time a column is added or removed?
>
> Is it possible to use named ranges in queries to solve this problem?

Yes, you could use named ranges instead of built-in column headers but the basic idea is the same as other answers to this an other similar questions in this site suggested: the spreadsheet should be set **to build a dynamic SQL string**.

Let say that `J` and `G` corresponds to named ranges `Grades` and `Class` respectively.

---

The following approach works only when the columns are between the columns A and Z

---

`CELL("address",Grades)` will return `"$J:$J"`. To get the column reference use `MID(CELL("address",Grades),2,1)` to get `"J"`. The final formula is

```
=QUERY(B:J,"SELECT AVG("&
MID(CELL("address",Grades),2,1)&
") GROUP BY "&
MID(CELL("address",Class),2,1))
```

---

The following approach works for all cases

---

`COLUMN(Grades)` will return an integer (a number of the form 1,2,3 etc.) To simplify the formula to create the SQL statement argument I suggest to force SQL to use column references of the form COL1, COL2, etc. by using the array notation (`{B:J}`). The final formula is

```
=QUERY({B:J},"SELECT AVG(Col"&COLUMN(Grades)-1&") GROUP BY Col"&COLUMN(Class)-1)
```

[Demo Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18z9sMVEmX0JFO9XnPf7-LaPlG3TIhy_Za-XIf3fPHKQ/edit?usp=sharing)

## References

[Using arrays in Google Sheets - Google Docs editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276?hl=en)

Answer (score 1):

[Ruben's answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/33840/is-it-possible-to-use-named-ranges-in-google-spreadsheet-queries-so-that-the-col/97545#97545) doesn't solve the problem for all cases because `MID(CELL("address",Grades),2,1)` fails if the `Grades` range is moved to a double-letter column like `$AA:$AA`.

In that case, the formula `MID(CELL("address",Grades),2,2)` is needed. For named ranges that span or abut the `$Z:$AA` range, this formula becomes problematic.

The formula `REGEXEXTRACT( CELL("address", Grades), "\$([a-zA-Z]+)\$")` solves the problem for the general case, but I strongly question its CPU efficiency when used all over a large spreadsheet.

Comment: In my [answer](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/97545/88163) there are two approachs but this answer only critizes one of them. The second approach should work for all cases.

Comment: I dont think this will work for named ranges that are on on different sheets.  Wondering if +2 years since, if there are better solutions to this...such as simply being able to reference the darn named ranges in the query itself

Answer (score 0):

I came across [this page](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/named-ranges-in-query-in-google-sheets/) at infoinspired.com that explains one way of doing it.  I tested it exactly as in the example he gave and it worked.
The setup:

```
      A        B        F                                     G
 1  names     Age   =left(address(row(B1),column(B1),4))   =QUERY(A:B,"Select "&Age)
 2  joey      32
 3  nicole    26
 4  sally     66
```

His explanation of F1:  The ADDRESS formula which includes the ROW and COLUMN functions returns the cell address of B1.  The LEFT function extracts the first letter that is the column heading from it.

--- Click on cell F1 and then go to the menu Data > Named ranges and name the range "Age" (without quotation marks)

Now you can formulate your query as:  `=QUERY(A:B,"Select "&Age)`

He's got more complicated examples in his page that I'm about to test now, but I'm encouraged that the first example worked!

Edit - sorry if this is exactly what others have been proposing with their answers. I just found this example crystal clear and was able to figure it out. Thought it might help others with the same question.

Answer (score 0):

I was also attempting to solve this issue and came up with a short script that allows you to write queries like this:

You use it like this:

```
=QUERY(A9:C13, QueryByName(A9:C9, "SELECT `Name`, `country` WHERE `age`>7"))
```

You can easily replace the two ranges above with named ranges if desired, and if a new column is added to the data set at a later point, you shouldn't need to update the query.

[image: Using Google Sheets QUERY with column headings/labels instead of letter]

I posted the code and more detailed instructions in another thread, **[see here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/155456/20364)**.