# QueryByName() function from another sheet in google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-custom-function

[image: item.toLowerCase error on line 26]

Is it possible to use the `QueryByName()` function using another sheet from the same spreadsheet?

```
=query(nor9609s!A1:Z500,querybyname(A1:Z1,"SELECT `Items_shopid` WHERE `Items_id`>0"))
```

I got error on `item.toLowerCase` on line 26.

Data from the other sheets (I try use both upper and lower case header but it's not working):

[image: Data from another sheets]
[image]

I am using the QueryByName addon function of Google Sheets.

Update: I tried to change header name to one without underscores (_), still the same error.

https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/155456/284908

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. It's not clear what you mean by "Its not problem with the script right" specially because `QueryByName` is not a Google Sheets built-in function. Does it comes from a bounded script or from an add-on?

Comment: I use your addon function in google script  QueryByName() , maybe `// Use a regular expression to get a list of all strings inside `backticks`
  let fieldNamesInQuery = queryString.matchAll(/`([^`]+)`/g);` cannot use underscore '_' in the column header

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know what you mean by "your addon function in google script". My add-ons doesn't include that custom function.

Comment: im sorry..i ask wrong person...so sorry

Comment: Instead of adding formulas as image the best is to add them as text. Also is better to add the most simple formula needed to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

From the question:

1. Formula

   > ```
   > =query(nor9609s!A1:Z500,querybyname(A1:Z1,"SELECT `Items_shopid` WHERE `Items_id`>0"))
   > ```
2. Error message:

   > TypeError: item.toLowerCase is not a function (line 26)

Apparently the code line from the QueryByName custom function that in your case is throwing the referrerd error message is the following:

```
  // Lowercase all heading names so that case errors are accepted
  const headings = columnHeadings[0].map(item => item.toLowerCase());
```

The error occurs because there some values in `A1:Z1` that aren't a string. One the way to fix this is to convert these values to  text values. I.E. the following formula use `TO_TEXT` and `ArrayFormula`:

```
=ArrayFormula(query(nor9609s!A1:Z500,querybyname(TO_TEXT(A1:Z1),"SELECT `Items_shopid` WHERE `Items_id`>0")))
```

NOTES:

The formula shown in the screenshot is not using backticks, it's using apostrophes. Please read carefully the instructions from the [referred answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/155456/284908).

You might found helpful the programming section of the following resources:

- Wikipedia's article about backticks / grave accent:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_accent
- Wikipedia's article about apostrophes / single quote https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostrophe

Comment: Yes my mistake, i did change to backtick, still same error

Comment: @lochoe Answer updated.