# Query based on column header in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I am trying to automate Worship list using Google Sheets, so it works good but one thing I can't do can be more than useful.

I have a sheet like this:

[image: Source Data]

in row 1 dates and below songs used that Sunday.

As a result, I need the table like this, where I can see when the song was used last time:

[image]

`MATCH` works good with one column, but how can I do it with multi-column range?

I've also tried to join columns to strings:

```
=join(",",A2:A7)
```

[image]

And then use `QUERY`:

```
=query(A$12:B$15,"select max(A) where B like '%"&F1&"%' label max(A) ''")
```

And it works, but not automatically...

Comment: You could nest a where clause inside a query which pulls up certain dates, you could also have a static list of dates and use a vlookup? Do you have a sample sheet?

Comment: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/146781/256097 allows for a query using column headers.

Answer (score 0):

I [created a sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uk9v_gczgY7uJXxzE049gKJkOguib6zteO17Mq_KNQ0/edit?usp=sharing) from your data, with a few more columns.

Basically, I took raw data, and added another row immediately underneath the date header. This new row contains `=JOIN(";",A4:A9)`, and is copied to each cell in the row.

To produce the desired output, I simply did an HLOOKUP on the dates and the joined data (with a SORT to put it in the correct order). Here is the formula I used:

```
=HLOOKUP("*"&D12&"*",TRANSPOSE(SORT(TRANSPOSE($A$2:$G$3),2,FALSE)),2,FALSE)
```

D12 contains "Song1" in this case. A2:G3 contains the dates and the songs joined together.

I'm sure there are better methods to accomplish what you want, especially ones which don't require copying multiple formulas to a lot of cells. I just did this as a quick proof of concept.